# Using Primefaces charts in a DataTable

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I want to use a LineChart in a DataTable. On each 'row' I want a different LineChart. Before I've used the GraphicImage tag to connect to jFreeChart and pass the objId of the object i want to plot by using the following snippet (where car is my DataTable variable from a SessionScoped backing bean's cars array):

```
<p:graphicImage value="#{carBean.graphById}">
    <f:param name="objId" value="#{car.objId}" />
</p:graphicImage>
```

The objId was then retrieved in the backing bean by checking the request parameter map:

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
String objId = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("objId");
```

This was all working fine. However now I want to use the funkier PrimeFaces charts so I figured that it should be quite easy to replace using the following code:

```
<p:lineChart value="#{carBean.graphById" title="Linear Chart" style="width:400px;" widgetVar="chart"  >
    <f:param name="objId" value="#{car.objId}" />
</p:lineChart>
```

The backing bean method ofcourse returns a `CartesianChartModel` instead of `StreamedContent`. The problem now is that `context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("objId")` returns null instead of the actual id as it used to do. f:params does not seem to work in the same way for `lineChart` as it does for `graphicImage`?

How would I achieve the same result for lineChart? Can I somehow get a variable passed to the backing bean so that the bean knows what values to put in the series?

I'm using Primefaces 3.5 and JSF 2.1 on Glassfish 3.1.2.

Comment: I can't understand why you are not using the `var` attribute of the dataTable for your purpose.

Comment: My var attribute is 'car', so you suggest that I should have a car.graph sort of method?

Comment: Yes, if I understand well this should be in line with your purpose.

Comment: There is no way of doing it the way that I'm attempting to? The reason is that the cars are 'JPA beans' and I think it would be cleaner if the graphing/plotting code could be separated from the bean itself (which is basically just a data container), mainly because the JPA beans are mainly used in other situations and this graph function is really just a 'side note'. Adding the code to the car bean itself could make it more complex than what it need to be for most of the usage scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since JSF 2.1 you can pass objects using EL:

```
<p:lineChart value="#{carBean.getGraphByCar(car)" ... />
```

or, if you want to use the `objId` property of car, use:

```
<p:lineChart value="#{carBean.getGraphByCarId(car.objId)" ... />
```

Comment: How would the receiving method look in the backing bean? How would the supplied variable/object be accessed?

Comment: If i change the receiving method in the backing bean to accept (String ojbId) or (Car car) i get the error that the method is not found. But if i do not add parameters to the method I do not get the error. I'm using the Mojarra 2.1.6 JSF implementation.

Comment: Obviously I should call the exact method name and not assume it puts get/set in front. Your solution worked fine, thanks alot for your help!